# Using strtok and get "cannot convert 'char*' to 'char**' in assignment"

Tags: c++, arduino, strtok

I am trying to make a program that reads a string from a file in SPIFFS with 4 tab-separated things and then processes it into four char arrays to be used in another function. However, I get the error `cannot convert 'char*' to 'char**' in assignment`. Is there any idea why? Here's my code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include "FS.h"
#include "AdafruitIO_WiFi.h"
char *ssid;
char *pass;
char *aiduser;
char *aidkey;
// comment out the following two lines if you are using fona or ethernet
#include "AdafruitIO_WiFi.h"
//AdafruitIO_WiFi io(IO_USERNAME, IO_KEY, WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASS);
void setupWifi(char* *aiduser, char* *aidkey, char* *ssid, char* *pass){

#define WIFIFILE "/config.txt"
int addr = 0;
bool spiffsActive = false;

if (SPIFFS.begin()) {
      spiffsActive = true;
 }
 File f = SPIFFS.open(WIFIFILE, "r");
 String str;
 while (f.position()<f.size())
        {
          str=f.readStringUntil('\n');
          str.trim();
        } 

// Length (with one extra character for the null terminator)
int str_len = str.length() + 1; 

// Prepare the character array (the buffer) 
char char_array[str_len];

// Copy it over 
str.toCharArray(char_array, str_len);
   const char s[2] = {9, 0};

   /* get the first token */
   aiduser = strtok(char_array, s);
   aidpass = strtok(NULL, s);
   ssid = strtok(NULL, s);
   pass = strtok(NULL, s);

   /* walk through other tokens 
   while( token != NULL ) {
      printf( " %s\n", token );

      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }*/
   // RESULT: A thingy
}

void setup(){
setupWifi(&aiduser, &aidkey, &ssid, &pass);

AdafruitIO_WiFi io(aiduser, aidkey, ssid, pass);}
```

Also, I can't run the `setupWifi` function unless it is in setup or loop, but I can't make it in another setup because this is #included into another main file.

Comment: Isn't your compiler telling you which line caused the error?

Comment: It says the lines from `/* get the first token */` to `/* walk through other tokens` are affected by the error.

Comment: You need to assign to the variables pointed at by the function parameters: `*aiduser = strtok(char_array, s);
  *aidpass = strtok(NULL, s);
  *ssid = strtok(NULL, s);
  *pass = strtok(NULL, s);`.

Comment: I have seen many wierd styles, and though style is "*not important*", this certainly freaked me out `char* *aiduser`!!! Read about pointers, because you really don't know the levels of indirection of the pointers in this code. Understanding pointers takes time, but once you do you can't think of a programming language where pointers are discouraged, or they replace them with "*references*". And you will be surprised to say "*understanding pointers takes time*"! But I know that, because I went through it!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't think this is a good idea, because `*aiduser`, `aidpass` would then be pointing to `char_array + some_offset` which is only valid when `setupWifi` is running.

Comment: @Pablo: Hmm — yes, you're right.  I suppose that means `*aiduser = strdup(strtok(char_array, s));` etc — though I'd want to check for nulls before handing the results of `strtok()` to `strdup()`, whereas it didn't matter before.  The notation fixes the compilation warnings; the notation doesn't fix the flawed semantics.  The desired result isn't clearly explained.  There are good reasons why that was a comment!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, I agree

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because of this:

```
void setupWifi(char* *aiduser, char* *aidkey, char* *ssid, char* *pass)
{
    ...
    aiduser = strtok(char_array, s);
    aidpass = strtok(NULL, s);
    ssid = strtok(NULL, s);
    pass = strtok(NULL, s);
}
```

This variables are double pointers, `strtok` returns a pointer to `char`, those
are not compatible types.

Because `strtok` returns `char_array + some_offset` and `char_array` is a local
variable in `setupWifi`, you need to do a copy for each of them and return the
copy instead. You can do it with `strdup`.

```
    *aiduser = strdup(strtok(char_array, s));
    *aidpass = strdup(strtok(NULL, s));
    *ssid = strdup(strtok(NULL, s));
    *pass = strdup(strtok(NULL, s));
```

I encourage you to always check the return value of `strdup`, because it can
return `NULL`.<sup>1</sup>

If your system does not have `strdup`, then you can write your own:

```
char *strdup(const char *text)
{
    if(text == NULL)
        return NULL;

    char *copy = calloc(strlen(text) + 1, 1);
    if(copy == NULL)
        return NULL;

    return strcpy(copy, text);
}
```

One last thing:

```
void setupWifi(char* *aiduser, char* *aidkey, char* *ssid, char* *pass);
```

It looks really awkward, never seen declaring double pointer this way. Much
easier to read would be

```
void setupWifi(char **aiduser, char **aidkey, char **ssid, char **pass);
```

---

**Fotenotes**

<sup>1</sup>While the syntax is correct, I still consider this bad practice,
because you should always check the return values of functions that return
pointers. If they return `NULL`, you cannot access the memory. This adds a
little bit of more code, but your program will not die of segfaults and it can
recover from the errors.

I'd also change your function to return 1 on success, 0 otherwise:

```
int parse_and_set(char *txt, const char *delim, char **var)
{
    if(delim == NULL || var == NULL)
        return 0;

    char *token = strtok(txt, delim);

    if(token == NULL)
        return 0;

    token = strdup(token);

    if(token == NULL)
        return NULL;

    *var = token;
    return 1;
}

void init_parse(char ***vars, size_t len)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        **(vars + i) = NULL;
}

int cleanup_parse(char ***vars, size_t len, int retval)
{
        for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            free(**(vars + i));
            **(vars + i) = NULL;
        }
}

int setupWifi(char **aiduser, char **aidkey, char **ssid, char **pass)
{
    if(aiduser == NULL || aidkey == NULL || ssid == NULL || pass == NULL)
        return 0;

    ...

    /* get the token token */

    char **vars[] = { aiduser, aidkey, ssid, pass };
    size_t len = sizeof vars / sizeof *vars;

    init_parse(vars, len);

    if(parse_and_set(char_array, s, aiduser) == 0)
        return cleanup_parse(vars, len, 0);

    if(parse_and_set(NULL, s, aidpass) == 0)
        return cleanup_parse(vars, len, 0);

    if(parse_and_set(NULL, s, ssid) == 0)
        return cleanup_parse(vars, len, 0);

    if(parse_and_set(NULL, s, pass) == 0)
        return cleanup_parse(vars, len, 0);



    ...

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: And when the OP has learned about structures, the code can be simplified by passing a pointer to a structure which contains members for each of the four fields.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes I agree again.

Comment: Update 5 years later - wow I really had no idea what I was doing, rest assured I know what pointers and structs are now and I don't use that horrendous pointer style anymore